# Webpack ignoring images files

Tags: webpack

I just start learn some front end technologies watching tutorials on youtube. Eveything was fine to the moment when I need to add images to my project. Some reason my webpack config ignoring my images files.

webpack config:

```
'use strict'
const path = require('path')
const utils = require('./utils')
const config = require('../config')
const vueLoaderConfig = require('./vue-loader.conf')

function resolve (dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
}

const createLintingRule = () => ({
  test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
  loader: 'eslint-loader',
  enforce: 'pre',
  include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')],
  options: {
    formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter'),
    emitWarning: !config.dev.showEslintErrorsInOverlay
  }
})

module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? config.build.assetsPublicPath
      : config.dev.assetsPublicPath
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': resolve('src'),
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      ...(config.dev.useEslint ? [createLintingRule()] : []),
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: vueLoaderConfig
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test'), resolve('node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client')]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        progressive: true,
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('media/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  node: {
    // prevent webpack from injecting useless setImmediate polyfill because Vue
    // source contains it (although only uses it if it's native).
    setImmediate: false,
    // prevent webpack from injecting mocks to Node native modules
    // that does not make sense for the client
    dgram: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    child_process: 'empty'
  }
}
```

and my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm">
        <img src="images/logo.svg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm">
        test
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm">
        O
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="app">
    <!--vue-->
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Webpack compiling css and fonts and js but only ignoring images. I can't find any reason why.

After run dev html doesn't see any images, but vue see it.
How to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: The problem should be in the loader you use for images. Are you absolutely sure that your images's size are under the 1000 bytes limit? Are you absolutely sure the path is correct? Are you absolutely sure the regex is correct? Can you try to use `file-loader` instead to check? https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/

Comment: This is a base config from "vue init webpack project-name" command. And file is only 13Kb.

Comment: Interesting. Then it narrows it down to your images maybe being over 1000 bytes, or being in the wrong location (this last is unlikely, if it's a starter project). Or something else I can't think of ^^

Comment: What do you mean wrong location? In config there is not specific source location for mg files? Or I'm wrong?

Comment: Well, the context of the Webpack build is `context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),` so your images should be in there somewhere ^^ But I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: It's correct. I try to put images file somewhere in base path next to css or js files as always.

Comment: Did you figure out the size of your images? Is it under the limit?

Comment: All files in total has 495Kb

Comment: The `limit` option sets an upper limit of 1000 bytes per file. So all your images should be individually under 1kb to be handled by `url-loader`. If they are more than 1kb, they won't be handled. I suggest you try removing the `limit` option from the coonfig to see if it fixes your problems.

Comment: No, didn't help :(

Comment: Then maybe try replacing `url-loader` with `file-loader` https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader